# How to load large files in C# Windows app

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm trying to create a Windows app that will load several large log files approx 30MB each.

What is the best approach here because I have tried loading it using the `RichTextBox` control but that will block the client for a long period of time before showing the files.

i have tried loading the log file using this code

```
 textBox1.Text = File.ReadAllText(Path + "\\Data.log");
```

I have tried using a `TextBox` and `RichTextBox` control

Comment: Threading will help, also look into filestreams, but I'd load in a thread, that way the UI stays responsive.

Comment: I suggest to make that loading async, this way your UI will not get block

Comment: Why would you chose a bulky control and not use the proper name? RichTextBox  VTC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            using (var sr = new StreamReader("path"))
            {
                do
                {
                    var line = sr.ReadLine();
                    sb.Append(line);
                } while (!sr.EndOfStream);
            }
            textBox1.Text = sb.ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can virtually split the file into chunks and then load this chunks by purpose. For example, when you open your editor, you load only part of the file (one or a few chunks) and then when a user scrolls down - you load a few more and so on. A size of chunks depends on how much info you show when users open the editor.

As an example for `RichTextBox`, you can try this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18124897/2313116), but you still need to determine which size of chunks is optimal for you.

Answer (score 1):

I'd personally recommend `System.IO` + threading.

Example:

```
string[] files = ["file1.txt", "file2.txt"];
void Main() {
     var th = new Thread(readFiles);
     th.Start();
}

void readFiles() {
    foreach (string file in files) {
        var fileContents = "";
        fileContents = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(file);
        // do something
    }
}
```

Comment: That does not address his main question of how to make the UI stay responsive...

Comment: I have already tried
 textBox2.Text = File.ReadAllText(Path + "\\data.log");
but that blocks the app

Comment: @FredrikNorling Doing it with threading shouldn't do that. Check newest edit.